Azure- Unable to login with the service principal
I am trying to login with service principal  after app registration.
i have below details used for login
az login --service-principal -u <secret_value> -p <application_clientId> --tenant <tenantID>

But i am getting below error

AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'erfhfgOs~SPAghgrr45hgf' was not found in the directory 'Default Directory'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I tried with new app, but failing all the time with above error
Any solution

you are mixing up client id and secret. use -u <application_client_id> -p <secret_value>

Initially I got the same error as below:
az login --service-principal -u <secret_value> -p <application_clientId> --tenant <tenantID>



Application with identifier 'erfhfgOs~SPAghgrr45hgf' was not found in the directory 'Default Directory'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid or wrong values for the parameters.
I agree with @cedric, you are passing client secret for client id parameter (u) and client id for client secret parameter (p).
To resolve the error, modify the command by passing correct values:
az login --service-principal -u <application_clientId> -p <secret_value> --tenant <tenantID> --allow-no-subscriptions

I am able to successfully login to az cli like below:


You can make use of  --allow-no-subscriptions to have tenant level access and if the subscriptions are not linked.


According to Azure CLI login with a Microsoft Entra ID service principal, you need the following information to az login using SP.
az login --service-principal -t <Tenant-ID> -u <Client-ID> -p <Client-secret>

Go to the Overview page of your SP, get the Tenant ID and Client ID.

Go to Certificates & secrets -> Client secrets. Get the value of Client secret.


hi @Ziyang i tried with above approach, but getting the same error
"No subscriptions found for 23dsdwweq."

@ hari_azure, After creating a service principal in the Azure Tenant you need to give this new SP some roles within a subscription. Go to your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment based on your needs. See the detailed info from Assign a role to the application. If you expect the SP to have no subscriptions, you can use the --allow-no-subscriptions flag with the az login command.
